# Как сделать авторизацию на вп сайте через заголовки запроса?

Tags: wordpress, авторизация

Имеется юзер (известны логин и пароль), надо его авторизовать на сайте так что бы при заходе на сайте он уже был известен сайту и видел нужный ему контент.
Все это работает в webview (webview показывает страницу сайта) приложения написанного на react native, то есть юзер приложения и юзера сайта одинаковые, надо каким то образом залогинить юзера на сайте, что бы при показе webview юзер был уже залогинен на сайте.
как можно это сделать ?

Answer (score 1):

`wp_set_auth_cookie` авторизирует пользователя в систему ВП. Но сначала нужно проверить доступы через `wp_authenticate`. Пример:

```
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

// пробуем получить юзера
$auth = wp_authenticate( $username, $password );

// Проверка ошибок
if ( is_wp_error( $auth ) ) {
    $error_string = $auth->get_error_message();
    echo '<div id="message" class="error"><p>' . $error_string . '</p></div>';
} else {
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_obj->ID );
}
```

Comment: не думаю что получится, первый запрос идет через cURL, там некуда ставить куки

Comment: Авторизация в ВП идет через куки, извините)

Comment: Без них вас точно не пустит в админку)

Comment: я знаю что через куки ) вот ищу способ как можно это обойти. и мне не нужно в админку, мне нужно что сайт показывал нужный контент юзеру

Comment: А в чем проблема с курла получить ответ и потом поставить куку?